# How can I detect a Gameobject touching another gameObject without using collider2D's?

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection

I have fish gameObjects that have colliders2D so that I can click and move them. I added fish food with Collider2D's but it was hard for me to click on the fish. After I disabled the fish food collider2D it was easier to click on the fish. Is there an alternative when detecting two gameObjeccts without colliders?

Comment: Why don't you simply put the fish food on a different layer, and ignore that layer in your fish-click detection script? Getting rid of colliders seems like the wrong solution to this problem.

Comment: I tried Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(algae.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>(), GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>()); but didn't work and i changed the Physics2D from project settings to ignore the fish food

Comment: I'm also using OnMouseDown() for click

Comment: Well there's your mistake.

Comment: lol OnMouseDown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `OnMouseDown`. Having this in your project forces Unity to cast rays for you in the most generic way, which is often less efficient and less precise than casting them yourself.

Make your own script that can filter to the physics layer you care about.

```
public class FishClicker : MonoBehaviour {

    public LayerMask whatIsFish;

    public float clickRadius = 0.1f;

    void Update() {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            var mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            var hit = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(mousePos, clickRadius, whatIsFish);

            if (hit != null) {
                var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<Fish>();

                if (fish != null) { fish.DoClickThing(); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Cheers :)

Comment: Is there a way to draw the Physic2D.Overlap? So that I can see the radius to fine tune it.

Comment: `void OnDrawGizmos() { Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(mousePos, clickRadius); }`

Comment: Awesome Appreciate it

Comment: At the moment I have seven different colored kind of fish. For instance every time a blue fish is instantiated it has the blue fish script. Your code is moving multiple blue fish at the same time lol so does that mean each colored fish prefab needs its own script?

Comment: You should have one copy of the FishClicker script somewhere in your scene. You should not have a copy on every fish. Generally, a blue Fish should be just an instance of the Fish class distinguished by its data, not a new class. But if you need very different behaviour from your fish, you could have BlueFish and RedFish implement an IClickable interface and get the component by interface. Or separate the clickable component from the fish component entirely.

Comment: Yes the blue and red fish are fine because i put the code in there script. But multiple blue fish has the same script causing them all to move (turn in circular morion) at the same time. I tried putting it in the game manager but that didn't work well

Comment: That error is caused because you put this code into the BlueFish and RedFish scripts. Do not do that. This should be a separate class, and you should have just one instance of it in your scene. Post a new question if you need help solving a problem with your manager.

Comment: I put one instance of it on the scene. It works well with click but not with click drag (Input.GetMouseButton(0))

Comment: That's a different question than was asked. Please post a new question if you'd like help applying dragging with this kind of script.

Comment: Oh ok thank you